# My "damage" stat bar is flashing. What does it mean?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

When I open the menu to look at my stats, the bar that shows damage is "flashing" (well, it looks more like it keeps increasing from "0" to "max" over and over again at high speed, hence "flashing"). What does it mean?

It happened before, and I think it has something to do with the Bloody Lust and technology 2.

Items I have atm when the bar is flashing:
(Playing as Eve)
Dead bird, Whore of Babylon, Small Rock, Chocolate Milk, Technology 2, Jesus Juice, Stem Cells, Bloody Lust, Cat-o-nine-tails, Lil Chub, Grade 1 Cube of meat, Ouja board, Toothpicks

Comment: Are you talking about a boss's life bar?

Comment: @Aubergine I'm assuming he's talking about the stats screen in the pause menu, and specifically his damage stat.

Comment: @MrSmooth That definitely makes more sense.

Comment: As i said, "when i look at my stats", and "the bar that shows damage". I probably mean the screen where my stats are shown.

Comment: I have to say this simply sounds like a bug, much like I have Scolex and Pin rapidly alternating in the game's credits. What effect does this actually have on your damage?

Comment: It's a bit too late to ask that, since as you know, the game is constantly renewed. Tho since its technology 2, its a little bit too difficult to notice, since i noticed that at Necropolis, and i dont really take my time to count how fast i kill stuff considering that these indestructible (green) faces keep shooting asploding stuff at me XD. Tl;Dr I have no idea whether it actually increased my damage, but it probably didnt.

Comment: I've had this happen before as well, though according to my stats, I've never picked up Technology 2, Stem Cells or Bloody Lust. I always assumed it meant "charging shots" (ie, from Chocolate Milk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chocolate Milk is the culprit. I always had this question in my head as I had never seen anything like this and yesterday when i got chocolate milk I noticed it does indeed change your damage bar to a a flashing bar. It fills from left to right and then repeats while flashing.

What this is supposed to indicate is that your damage is relative to how long you spend charging the shot. The longer you hold down the fire key the stronger the shot is.